# Mysql Mutliple Column Row Duplicate, Deletion Statement

Tags: mysql

So im having trouble with getting this statement to work properly.
I have a table with 4 Columns: ID, CertID, GroupID, CompID.
Over time the database has gathered some duplicate rows, by that i mean a row that is Duplicate to another on all columns not including the ID Field which is its Key.

Ive always attempted to get a SELECT statment to work before the actual DELETE statement so that im not having to Restore a backed up DB.

This is what ive been trying recently:

```
SELECT u1.* FROM CertMain AS u1, CertMain AS u2 
WHERE u1.CertID = u2.CertID 
AND u1.GroupID = u2.GroupID 
AND u1.CompID = u2.CompID
```

But this doesnt seem to be giving me what I want, Any help is appreciated Thanks

```
----------------------------------
| ID | CertID | GroupID | CompID |
|----|--------|---------|--------|
| 1  |   1    |    4    |   1    | <---Duplicate Row
| 2  |   1    |    4    |   3    | <---NOT A Duplicate Row (All 3 must match)
| 3  |   1    |    4    |   1    | <---Duplicate Row
| 4  |   8    |    3    |   5    |
| 5  |  10    |    1    |   1    |
----------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just using `group by`?

```
select CertID, GroupID, CompID, group_concat(id)
from CertMain
group by CertID, GroupID, CompID 
having count(*) > 1;
```

This puts all the ids on one line.

If you want the actual rows, then use `exists`:

```
select cm.*
from CertMain cm
where exists (select 1
              from CertMain cm2
              where cm2.certid = cm.certid and cm2.groupid = cm.groupid and
                    cm2.compid = cm.compid and cm2.id <> cm.id
             );
```

EDIT:

If you want to turn this into a `delete` in MySQL, that's a bit more trouble.  If the `group by` has decent performance, then you can do:

```
delete cm
    from CertMain cm  join
         (select CertID, GroupID, CompID, min(id) as minid
          from CertMain
          group by CertID, GroupID, CompID 
         ) cm2
         on cm2.certid = cm.certid and cm2.groupid = cm.groupid and
            cm2.compid = cm.compid and cm.id > cm2.minid;
```

You should save the current table in another table before doing the delete.  Also note that this will not quite work as desired if any of the three ids are `NULL`.

Comment: So this appears to have accomplished my task, I will need more time to review the Output to be sure i  dont accidently delete anything. Im assuming a simple ID < ID would allow me to Delete all rows except 1?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HAVING COUNT` clause to locate duplicate rows, like this:

```
SELECT CertID, GroupID, CompID, count(*) as duplicated_rows
FROM CertMain
GROUP BY CertID, GroupID, CompID 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score -1):

From what you have currently you are finding that every row has a duplicate with itself, where `u1.ID = u2.ID`.
You need to compare `u1.ID > u2.ID`

```
SELECT u1.* FROM CertMain AS u1, CertMain AS u2 
WHERE u1.CertID = u2.CertID 
AND u1.GroupID = u2.GroupID 
AND u1.CompID = u2.CompID
AND u1.ID > u2.ID
```

Comment: No where in my Post did i mention using u1.ID = u2.ID.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I ment by u1.ID = u2.ID. In your search u1 and u2 are the same table, CertMain. That means that u1's first row and u2's first row are the same in all columns, and will be selected. So the select statement will at least contain 1 of each row from u1.

Comment: You were not dealing with when u1.ID = u2.ID which is why your select statement was not getting what you wanted.